# Calculating my 90 Schengen days precisely

Tags: schengen, us-citizens, visa-free-entry, 90-180-visa-rules

I am a US citizen and know the 90-day allotted rule.  But this time I need clarification.  I am entering France on May 18th and had planned on departing Spain on August 16th - exactly 90 days.
But I have booked a repositioning cruise that departs from Lisbon on August 26th.  So I think, or at least hope, I could depart Spain for the UK on August 14th or 15th and would still be able to return to Lisbon for 1 day on the 26th and still be within my 90 days?  Sure hope someone can answer this question for me before I confirm my cruise!

Added from a now deleted answer:
I have rearranged my departure from Spain to the UK to give myself a 4-day buffer before I would reach my 90-day limit in the Schengen. I will fly into Lisbon the morning of the 26th of August and the cruise departs (for the States) at 11:00 p.m. that evening.

Comment: August 16th is the 91st day. If you leave on August 16th as planned, you would be in violation of the 90-day limit. If you leave on the 14th, you'll have one day available. If you then return on the 26th, you also have to leave on the 26th. If you leave on the 27th, that would be two days, also taking you over the 90-day limit.

Comment: Is your cruise taking you back to the USA?

Comment: @BritishSam why would that make a difference?

Comment: Just wondered, sound a long cruise! Also just making sure it doesn't go back into the Schengen area.

Answer (score 7):

Using the Schengen calculator https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en entering on 18th May and leaving on 14th August will allow you to renter on 26th for one day within the 90/180 day rule.

Bear in mind that ‘For one day’ means exactly that - you will need to enter and leave on the same day, and before 23:59. You must make sure you receive entry and exit stamps. Since you do not have any room for error if there are any delays to your travel plans, you should consider how you can spend a little less time in the Schengen zone to give yourself more of a buffer. For example, arriving in Schengen a little later, leaving for the UK a day or so earlier.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is using exactly all of your days with no margin for errror. If your cruise is delayed or anything else goes wrong, you will be overstaying.

Comment: Since the question implies a misunderstanding of how the days are counted, it should be emphasized that "for one day" means leaving on the same day as arriving.  In other words, a one-day visit means receiving a departure stamp with the same date as the arrival stamp, which requires departing before midnight.

Comment: Thanks for taking up my comment.  The amount of time spent in the UK has no direct bearing on the problem, though; to create a buffer to allow for changes in plans, it's necessary to spend *less* time in the Schengen area.  This could be achieved by postponing the arrival until later than 18 May or by departing earlier than 14 August.

Comment: @Phoog Sorry, that’s what I meant to explain!